# Cell events on a disabled DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, disable

I have a `DataGridView` on a Form. I need keep it disabled for view mode only, no highlight selected row and etc.

One column with an image must be clickable, with hand cursor.
The `CellClick` an `CellMouseEnter" events didn't fire because the grid is disabled.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

First, define some properties using the `DataGridView` Designer.
Select the `DataGridView`, in it's Properties List, locate [DefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle.SelectionForeColor);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle.Alignment);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) and open the editor.

We need to set the `SelectionForeColor` and `SelectionBackColor` equal to the `ForeColor` and `BackColor` properties. This will prevent a modification of the Cell Color when selected.
Here, I'm setting `Color.White` for the `BackGround` and `Color.Black` for the `ForeGround`.
Change it to whatever you like, they just need to be the same for both *pairs*.

[image: DataGridView DefaultCellStyle Properties]

Right after you have set the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` (or inserted the Data rows in some other way), modify the [ReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.readonly?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) and, if needed, [Frozen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.frozen?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.Frozen);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) properties of all the Columns except the one that display the Images. Here, I'm simply using an `int` Field set to the Index of a Column.
It can also be derived by inspecting the `[Cell].ValueType` of each Column.

```
//Define which Column contains an Image
int ImageColumn = 2;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if (column.Index != ImageColumn)
    {
        column.Frozen = true;
        column.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Subscribe to the [CellMouseEnter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseenter?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CellMouseEnter);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle.SelectionForeColor);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle.Alignment);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) and [CellMouseLeave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseleave?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CellMouseLeave);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle.SelectionForeColor);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle.Alignment);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) events.
These are used to change the Cursor to the classic Hand form when the Mouse pointer enters a Cell containing an Image and to reset it to the default value when it leaves it.

Here, I'm subscribing to the events in the Form's constructor, but you could also use the event handlers generated by the Designer through the Events List of the `DataGridView` Control.

```
public form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.dataGridView1.CellMouseEnter += (s, e) => 
        { if (e.ColumnIndex == ImageColumn) dataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Hand; };

    this.dataGridView1.CellMouseLeave += (s, e) => 
        { if (e.ColumnIndex == ImageColumn) dataGridView1.Cursor = Cursors.Default; };
}
```